# Rename a list of files

Tags: powershell

I need to rename all files below `pwd` named `all_v4_0.csv` to `all_v4_1.csv`.
So far, I have worked my way to this piece of PowerShell:

```psh
$oldfiles = dir -recurse | ?{$_.Name -eq "all_v4_0.csv"}
foreach ($o in $oldfiles) {
    $o.CopyTo Join-Path $o.Directory.ToString() "all_v4_1.csv"
}
```

But the `foreach` loop fails with the message that

```
At line:2 char:15
+     $o.CopyTo Join-Path $o.Directory.ToString() "all_v4_1.csv"
+               ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Join-Path' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

### Update, 20150604

As commented below by Manuel Batsching, the original version can be fixed by adding two layers of parentheses: one to indicate function argument, and one to force evaluation order:

```psh
$oldfiles = dir -recurse | ?{$_.Name -eq "all_v4_0.csv"}
foreach ($o in $oldfiles) {
    $o.CopyTo((Join-Path $o.Directory.ToString() "all_v4_1.csv"))
}
```

For the problem at hand, one of the solutions with `.FullName.Replace` would probably be easier.

Comment: Just for clarification: Do you want to rename the files in question or create a copy of them under a different name? In the code above you seem to attempt the latter. If you actually want to rename your files, `MoveTo()` would be a better choice.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching I need the files copied to a different name (next step is to edit some of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSH's parser is not reading the `Join-Path` and its arguments as an expression to evaluate and pass result to outer expression. So parentheses to force evaluation order.

But additionally `CopyTo` is a .NET member, rather than a PSH cmdlet, so it needs to have parentheses around its argument (and no space).

Thus:

```
$o.CopyTo((Join-Path $o.Directory.ToString() "all_v4_1.csv"))
```

(Possibly using PSH's `Copy-Item` cmdlet would be a cleaner option.)

Comment: Thanks -- I actually tried something along these lines, but it doesn't work: I get an "unexpected token" for the opening parenthesis

Comment: `CopyTo()` is a method. No whitespace is allowed between the method name and the opening parenthesis.

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Ok, thanks  -- but that just takes me back to the "Unexpected token 'Join-Path'"...

Comment: That is, because `CopyTo()` expects a string as argument. You still need another set of parenthesis to evaluate `Join-Path` before sending its return value as an argument to `CopyTo()`: `$o.CopyTo((Join-Path $o.Directory.ToString() "all_v4_1.csv"))`

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Yes, this works -- and I think I am starting to grok some PS :) If you add this approach to your answer, I'll mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Set the target name separately before doing the copy. The below should work:

```
$oldfiles = dir -recurse | ?{$_.Name -eq "all_v4_0.csv"}

foreach ($o in $oldfiles) {
    $newName = $o.FullName.replace("all_v4_0.csv","all_v4_1.csv")
    Copy-Item $o.FullName $newName
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works (as does `Copy-Item $o.FullName $o.FullName.replace("all_v4_0.csv","all_v4_1.csv")`. I would still like to understand why my own attempt fails though

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep things simple you can also use string concatenation to create the target path.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include 'all_v4_0.csv' | 
    ForEach { $_.MoveTo($_.Directory.FullName + '\all_v4_1.csv') }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the substring in the new name of the files:

```psh
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include 'all_v4_0.csv' |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('4_0', '4_1') }
```